# Count the number of rows in each column

Tags: c#, excel, interop

How can I count number of rows in specified column in a Excel sheet?

For example I have 2 columns in a spreadsheet:

```
A      B
---    -----
abc    hi 
fff    hello
ccc    hi
       hello
```

The result should look like:

```
count of A column is 3
count of B column is 4
```

How can I do this using Microsoft Interop?

Comment: Use `WorksheetFunction.COUNTA`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The approach suggested by Doug Glancy is accurate and simple to be implemented. You can write the function and retrieve the value from a cell not seenable by the user (ZZ1000, for example). The code is straightforward:

```
Range notUsed = curSheet.get_Range("ZZ1000", "ZZ1000");
string targetCol = "A";
notUsed.Value2 = "=COUNTA(" + targetCol + ":" + targetCol + ")";
int totRows = Convert.ToInt32(notUsed.Value2);
notUsed.Value2 = "";
```

UPDATE ---

From your example I understood that you were looking for the total number of non-empty cells, what `COUNTA` delivers. But, apparently, this is not the case: you want the row number of the last non-empty cell; that is, by using a more descriptive example:

```
 C
---   
abc    
fff    
ccc    

hello
```

You don't want to count the number of non-empty cells (4 in this case; what `COUNTA` delivers), but the position of "hello", that is, 5.

I don't like relying on Excel formulae too much, unless for clearly-defined problems (like yours, as I understood it initially). Excel formulae deliver still the best solution for what you really want (although its complexity is right "in the limit"). To account for the situation as described above, you can rely on `MATCH`. If your cells contain text (at least one letter per cell), the code can be changed into:

```
notUsed.Value2 = "=MATCH(REPT(\"z\",255)," + targetCol + ":" + targetCol + ")";
```

In case of having numeric values (not a single letter in the cell):

```
notUsed.Value2 = "=MATCH(LOOKUP(" + Int32.MaxValue.ToString() + "," + targetCol + ":" + targetCol + ")," + targetCol + ":" + targetCol + ")";
```

If you want to account for both options, you would have to combine these equations: you can create a new formula including both; or you might rely on C# code (e.g., get the values from both equations and consider only the bigger one).

Bear also in mind that you have to account for cases where no matches are found. Here you have a code accounting for both situations (letters and numbers via C# code) and for no matches:

```
notUsed.Value2 = "=MATCH(REPT(\"z\",255)," + targetCol + ":" + targetCol + ")";
int lastLetter = Convert.ToInt32(notUsed.Value2);
if (lastLetter == -2146826246)
{
    lastLetter = 0;
}
totRows = lastLetter;

notUsed.Value2 = "=MATCH(LOOKUP(" + Int32.MaxValue.ToString() + "," + targetCol + ":" + targetCol + ")," + targetCol + ":" + targetCol + ")";
int lastNumber = Convert.ToInt32(notUsed.Value2);
if (lastNumber == -2146826246)
{
    lastNumber = 0;
}

if (lastNumber > totRows)
{
    totRows = lastNumber;
}
```

Comment: Hi Varo. This doesnt work if I have empty rows in between.I still want to get the last row .How to ignore empty rows in between?

Comment: @CoolDiva, COUNTA works perfectly with empty rows. The problem is that you want something different than what this function delivers (your example wasn't too clear). I will update my answer right now.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
private static int GetRowsInColumnOnWorkSheetInWorkbook(string workbookName, int worksheetNumber, int workSheetColumn)
{
    return new Excel.Application().Workbooks.Open(workbookName)
        .Sheets[worksheetNumber]
        .UsedRange
        .Columns[workSheetColumn]
        .Rows
        .Count;
}
```

You could have the following override also:

```
private static int GetRowsInColumnOnWorkSheetInWorkbook(string workbookName, string worksheetName, int workSheetColumn)
{
    return new Excel.Application().Workbooks.Open(workbookName)
        .Sheets[worksheetName]
        .UsedRange
        .Columns[workSheetColumn]
        .Rows
        .Count;
}
```

It's slightly longer than the other answer, but I think this is more readable, and simpler.

Comment: Will this work if I have empty rows in between? I want to ignore empty rows.